# Need suggestions on what tool to use for manipulating a file

Tags: sql, file, text, import, export

We have a need to create a daily process that will manipulate a file that is now being manually generating before FTPing it to a vendor. The issues with the current file are as follows:

1) It is currently comma delimited and it needs to be pipe delimited.

2) The vendor only want specific columns to be sent. They have a limit of 26 columns.

We need to develop an automated process that can be scheduled to run once a day and pick up a file with a specific extension, do the file manipulation and FTP the file.

Ideally, we would like to have some error handling in the process. We would want an email to get sent out if there was no file to process or if there was an error during the manipulation or FTP process.

My first thought was to use SQL Server Import/Export. I've done this before but that was only for packages that could be run manually. This process needs to be fully automated (after the existing file is manually generated.) I don't see a way to pick up any file with a specific extension. It looks like I have to select a specific file.
Is there a way to use Import/Export or some similar tool?
Or, do I need to write a program to do this sort of task? It seems to me like it would be more work to write a program. So, I am trying to avoid that.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should write a program.  Seriously.